# Cannot Convert String To Float

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, csv, numbers

I have a csv file with the following values in string form:

```
'838.5',
'830.090027',
'820',
'827.559998',
'822.880005'
```

And am reading the file like this:

```
file = []
for line in open('project.csv'):
    our_data = line.split(",")

    data.append(our_data)
```

I have tried to convert these to floats in the following way:

```
data = [float(x) for x in file]
```

But I get this error when I run the program:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: .

How can I solve this problem without having to edit the csv file?

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: `file = []
for line in open('project.csv'):
    our_data = line.split(",")

    data.append(our_data)`

Comment: Could you add that to your question. It would make things easier for everyone who may be trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Always more than one way to skin a cat, but here's what I'd do:

```
# Read the entire contents of the file into a string (`numbers`).
# This includes newline characters and single-quotes.
with open('project.csv') as infile:
    numbers = infile.read()

# Then remove the newline characters and single-quotes
# (replace each with the empty string, thus removing them)
# resulting in a string with numbers separated by commas
# e.g., `123.3,45.9,39.1`
numbers = numbers.replace("'","").replace("\n","")

# Then create a new list by splitting the string on comma
# and converting each individual item to a float
numbers = [float(num) for num in numbers.split(',')]
```

Notes:

- If the file is really big, you might want to iterate line-by-line rather than read the whole file in.
- If the input file might contain formatting errors, you'd have to be more careful to avoid unanticipated exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The original file contains the quotes and the break line (\n), but you are only trying to get rid of the break line (but still not done yet). First you need to extract the string(the quotes and the numbers) from the output of `split()`, second you need to get rid of the quotes, then use float(...) to convert them into floats:

```
for line in open('project.csv'):
    our_data = line.split(",")
    print our_data
    our_data = our_data[0][1:-1]
    print our_data
    print float(our_data)
```

Will give you the output:

```
["'838.5'", '\n']
838.5
838.5
["'830.090027'", '\n']
830.090027
830.090027
["'820'", '\n']
820
820.0
["'827.559998'", '\n']
827.559998
827.559998
["'822.880005'"]
822.880005
822.880005
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some confusion about how to properly open and split up your file. This should work. Your problem is that your reading each line from the file and then trying to split it. What your actual appending to `data` is something like this:

`['838.5', ',']`

And you then try to convert this to a float, which of course means Python will raise an error. Instead, read in your entire file, and then split it up. Filter out anything that is not a number, and then convert those to floats:

```
with open('project.csv') as file:
    file = file.readlines()

file = [el[1:-1] for line in file for el in line.split(',')]
floats = [float(el) for el in file if el]
```

**Value of `floats`:**

```
[838.5, 830.090027, 820.0, 827.559998, 822.880005]
```